# Entropy of perfect gas function of internal energy and number of particles

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas

In a statistical physics lecture, I found an equation describing the entropy $S$ of an ideal gas and it is said that equation can be obtained thanks to elementary thermodynamics formulae.
The equation is the following:
$$ S = N\left(c_\mathrm{v}\ln\left(\frac{U}{N}\right) + k_\mathrm{b}\ln\left(\frac{V}{N}\right)+ constant\right)$$
With

- $N$ the particle's number,
- $c_\mathrm{v}$ the heat capacity at constant volume ($dU = Nc_\mathrm{v}dT$) and $c_\mathrm{v} = \frac{3}{2}k_\mathrm{b}$ for monoatomic perfect gas, supposed T-independent
- $k_\mathrm{b}$ the Boltzmann constant
- and $V$ the volume of the gas

The problem is I cannot obtain that equation. I succeed in getting $\Delta S$ as a function of $(P,T)$, $(T,V)$, or $(P,V)$ but not as a function of $U$ and $N$. Could you help me?

Comment: It has to be U, V, and N, not just U and N.  If U an d N are constant, S can still increase if V is increased.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just the [Sackur-Tetrode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation) in disguise.

Taking the form from wikipedia we can quickly rearrange to your form:

$$
\frac{S}{K_B N} = \ln \left[\frac{V}{N}\left(\frac{4\pi m}{3 h^2}\frac{U}{N} \right)^{3/2} \right] + \frac{5}{2}
$$

or,

$$
S = N \left(K_B \ln \frac{V}{N} + \frac{3 K_B}{2} \ln \frac{U}{N} + \mathrm{constants} \right)
$$

which is the form you give.

The full derivation is the resolution of [the Gibbs Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox), and the linked wikipedia page contains the derivation.

However, if you've already got a form containing T rather than U, you're probably almost there. For a monoatomic ideal gas you have the relation:

$$
U = - \frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln Z = \frac{3}{2}K_B T
$$